# Assignin multiple values in cell arrays

Tags: matlab

I have the following repetitive code (if statement):

```
aaa = cell(3, 1);
aaa = {rand(20, 1); rand(20, 1); rand(20, 1)};
bbb = cell(3, 1);
for ii=1:20
    if (aaa{1,1}(ii, 1) <= 0.5)
        bbb{1,1}(ii, 1:3) = [0 1 0];
    else
        bbb{1,1}(ii, 1:3) = [1 0 0];
    end
    if (aaa{2,1}(ii, 1) <= 0.5)
        bbb{2,1}(ii, 1:3) = [0 1 0];
    else
        bbb{2,1}(ii, 1:3) = [1 0 0];
    end
    if (aaa{3,1}(ii, 1) <= 0.5)
        bbb{3,1}(ii, 1:3) = [0 1 0];
    else
        bbb{3,1}(ii, 1:3) = [1 0 0];
    end
...
end
```

The code is working, however I'm curious to know how I could remove the 3 if statement to replace it with just 1 (might be possible to remove the for loop as well). I've checked the cellfun function, however I didn't find how to interract with the array that are inside each cell.

Comment: Do you really need to use cell arrays? 2D arrays seem more suitable to your data, and would let you avoid the if's and probably the loop quite easily

Comment: @LuisMendo I indeed, don't really need cell arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, slightly longer code (like yours) is much easier to read and ultimately easier to debug.  That said, here is a solution without any explicit for or if statements.  Some may argue that this is done implicitly.

```
ccc = cell(3,1);
tempmat = [ones(20, 1) zeros(20, 2)]; %This initializes the else part of your ifs
ccc = {tempmat; tempmat; tempmat};

ind1 = find(aaa{1,1} < 0.5); %Finds all the cases when aaa is less than 0.5
ind2 = find(aaa{2,1} < 0.5);
ind3 = find(aaa{3,1} < 0.5);

ccc{1,1}(ind1,:) = repmat([0 1 0], length(ind1), 1);
ccc{2,1}(ind2,:) = repmat([0 1 0], length(ind2), 1);
ccc{3,1}(ind3,:) = repmat([0 1 0], length(ind3), 1);
```